# Displacement texture same size across different size of cubes

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I have two cubes of different sizes where I want to displace a texture on.  In this particular case a brick wall.  I want the bricks to be of uniform size on the small cube and on the bigger cube.  Yet on the bigger cube everything is scaled up together with the cubes scale.  How can I make the bricks uniform size on both cubes ?  I'm using UV unwrap so I only displace the front of the cube.  I found a few questions that seem to relate to my problem but they don't talk about displacement but just adding a texture.  I don't care about texture or color, I'm trying to make an STL for 3D printing.

[image: example cubes]

Edit: I tried the project from view as suggested and they look to be the same size now, however now I get these big bricks.  Which is not my desired result either.

[image: Big bricks]

Comment: The displacement is reading the UV.  Change the UV.  To make them the same size, enter edit on both, u->project from view.  You *are* dealing with textures here, and looking at texturing tutorials will help, even if they're talking about things you don't want to do-- good tuts teach about how things work below the surface, and sometimes, those tuts teach you by telling you about things in a domain that seems unrelated to your goal.

Comment: I tried the project from view, and I don't understand it do I need to resize the texture, cause if I resize the face on the UV, I get the same result as I had the first time.  Also what texture tutorial are you explicitly talking about ?

Comment: The problem I'm having has it something to do with Texel Density ?  I'm reading and watching on this at the moment

Comment: Hi :). As you probably know by now, yes, a uniform texel density is what you need. There are addons to help set it to uniform values across multiple objects.

Comment: So the problem I was having was not understanding Texel Density. For those who will encounter the same problem and come across my question. The following tutorials taught me all I needed to know to get everything to work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xp61tSQljz0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crnqlSR_ML8 I also needed following tool to get it to work in Blender. It's all explained in the youtube video's https://github.com/mrven/Blender-Texel-Density-Checker

Comment: I got it to work now I'll post an answer to my question with all the resources I used to understand the problem